# Dynamic Connection Manager in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have around 20 SSIS packages where my data moves from my OLEDb source to flat files.

My Source has stored procedure with a mixture of 12 tables.

Recently we have moved the data from DEV to PROD, since we have moved to prod, i need to make all the connection changes in the packages. in future i will have more than 40 SSIS packages which will be difficult to manually to change the connections.

I have tried using Environmental variable approach but some how that didn't work out. Is there any other approach.

Comment: Have a look at this [`How to: Add a Package Configuration`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140213(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? 2012/2014 or a prior version?

Comment: " some how that didn't work out." What is the actual problem? There are many online resources on using package configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I found out solution for my problem.

I have used XML Package configuration, where i have created a DTSCONFIG file and stored server name value in it.

So once my packages has moved to PROD environment, i have changed the servername value from DEV to PROD.